# error script_name.sh: line 13: [[0: command not found

Tags: shell, ksh

Good morning ! trying to execute this code but i have an error on if statement .
error message : error script_name.sh: line 6: [[0: command not found
the problèm is on "if" statement.
help please

```
#!/bin/ksh
jour=$(date +%Y%m%d)
#Control if run is ok or not before sending mail
dir_resultFailure=/transfertCLINK/Share/RESULT_UAT/$jour/FichierFailure/
dir_resultFilteredOut=/transfertCLINK/Share/RESULT_UAT/$jour/FichierFilteredOut/
if [[ `ls $dir_resultFailure | wc -l` -eq 0 ]] &&  [[`ls $dir_resultFilteredOut | wc -l` -eq 0 ]]
then
        echo "repo is empty."
fi
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have it in following way.

```
#!/bin/ksh
jour=$(date +%Y%m%d)
#Control if run is ok or not before sending mail
dir_resultFailure="/transfertCLINK/Share/RESULT_UAT/$jour/FichierFailure/"
dir_resultFilteredOut="/transfertCLINK/Share/RESULT_UAT/$jour/FichierFilteredOut/"
if [[ $(ls $dir_resultFailure | wc -l) -eq 0 ]] &&  [[ $(ls $dir_resultFilteredOut | wc -l) -eq 0 ]]
then
        echo "repo is empty."
fi
```

***Improvments/Fixes in OP's attempts:***

1. Always wrap your variables values inside `"`.
2. Using backticks is deprecated now, use `$(....)` for saving variables values.
3. Your `if` condition was not correct, you should have spaces in between `[[` and `(`.